# Python: convert all values in csv row to number

Tags: python

I have csv file with tab separated numbers in cells.

And I want to convert all values in row to numbers in array.

For example:
Input:

```
1 2 3 4
0 1 1 3
```

Output:

```
[1234, 0113]
```

How to do it?

Comment: What number do you want `0113` to be?

Comment: Your input does not look like a CSV file.  Do you probably just want to remove all spaces?

Comment: 5gon12eder, yes, I want to remove all \t

Comment: Burhan Khalid, I have binary mask in row's, and want to get array with this values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do **not** need `re`, just `split`, `str.join` and map to `int`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    nums = map(int,("".join(x.rstrip().split()) for x in f))
```

Or without using `map`:

```
 [int(s) for s in (x.rstrip().replace(" ","") for x in f)]
```

Using a file with 100 lines:

```
In [49]: %%timeit 
with open("in.txt") as f:
    nums = map(int,("".join(x.rstrip().split()) for x in f))
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 140 µs per loop

In [50]: %%timeit 
with open('in.txt', 'r') as istr:
    lines = [re.sub(r'\s*', '', line) for line in istr]
    [int(n) for n in lines]
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 519 µs per loop

In [53]: %%timeit
   ....: with open("in3.txt") as f:
   ....:     nums = [int(s) for s in (x.rstrip().replace(" ","") for x in f)]
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all spaces from each line, you can use regular expressions:

```
import re

lines = list()
with open('input.txt', 'r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        line = re.sub(r'\s*', '', line)
        lines.append(line)
```

Or, if you like it functional:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as istr:
    lines = [re.sub(r'\s*', '', line) for line in istr]
```

Note that the above examples will give you a list of strings.  If you want to convert them to integers, you can map the `int` builtin function onto it.

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in lines]
```

Comment: why on earth would you need a regex?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There is always more than one way to do it.  I think regular expressions are a reasonable way to go.  (What is nice about it is that it extends elegantly to cases where the separator is more than whitespace, say `\s*,\s*`.)  `split()` and `join()` would be another one.  And I think we could come up with many more solutions.

Comment: I think in this case for a simple tab delimited file with no remotely complicated patterns, using regex is not the way to go and would not encourage any person starting out to use regex in a case like this.